# How to allow specific html entities to display in ng-repeat while sanitizing the rest?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

So for this example, I have a list of strings I'm retrieving with $http, the strings can contain multiple spaces in a row, which in order to display properly I need to replace the strings with the nbsp html entity. It's also important to sanitize the strings as they're user provided. What would be the easiest way to keep $sce enabled to where the strings are properly sanitized but also after that is done, replace any spaces with the nbsp entity and have it displayed properly and not as the literal nbsp?

I put together a jsfiddle. I'm trying to make it so the string with Hello and a group of spaces in the word is displayed like it is, but I do not want the b entity markup to display in actual bold, I want it to be sanitized/escaped and display as the literal html tags like it usually would.

http://jsfiddle.net/J4nRK/40/

```
<div ng-app='myApp' ng-controller="Controller">
<ul>
   <li ng-repeat="item in items" ng-bind-html="item | includespaces">
       <!--{{ item }}-->
   </li>
</ul>
```

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('Controller', function ($scope, $sce) {
    // Assume this is data from $html.
    $scope.items = ['He       llo', 'Testing<b>bold</b>', 'bleh'];
});

app.filter('includespaces', ['$sce', function ($sce) {
    return function (text) {

        //return $sce.getTrustedHtml(text);
        return $sce.trustAsHtml(text.replace(/ /g, "&nbsp;"));
    }
}]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `pre`, maybe? No filter required at all.

```
<li ng-repeat="item in items">
  <pre ng-bind="item"></pre>
</li>
```

[image: imgur]